# Displaying JavaScript string obtained from DB as empty string when equal to null

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am using Ajax where the server queries a database using `SELECT someColumn FROM someTable`, returns someColumn to the client, and the client updates an element using `$('#someElement').text(someColumn);`

Works great unless someColumn returns null, in which the page displays "null" instead of my desired empty string.  Originally, I was dealing with this at the database level using `SELECT COALESCE(someColumn,'')`, however, am considering changing to the client level using `$('someElement').text(someColumn==null?'':someColumn);`  I am sure there are other solutions as well.  What is the best practice method to display null as nothing?

Comment: Am concerned this question may be "not constructive" insofar as it is "*likely solicit debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion*", but for what it's worth I'd retain the information that the value is `NULL` for as long as possible - i.e. handle that case in the client.

Comment: @eggyal.  I was concerned about asking this question as well, but finally decided there probably is a best practice and it will not result in endless debate.  I probably will go with your recommended approach of dealing with it at the client.

Comment: Use `json_encode()` on the data first, server-side. It will generate `'text'`, but also `null` which will achieve the desired result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try

```
$('#someElement').text(someColumn || '')
```

**Edit**

Will not work if `someColumn` is a numerical value and has a value that should be displayed, but evaluates to false. But it should work with string values.

Comment: Will this cause problems if someColumn is 0?

Comment: If it is the numerical value 0, then yes. If it is a string, then no.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try;

```
$('someElement').text(someColumn===null?'':someColumn);
```

Just to check the two are the same type.